# Android onTouch view returning null

Tags: android

in my `onTouch(View view, Motionevent event)` method, the `view.getY()` always returns the same (0.0). I want to check what view is being touched and compare it with `int Y = event.getRawY()`. Would something like this be possible?

The reason is that I have a couple of animated fields in my layout, and I would like to animate each view differently depending on which one is being touched. I will appreciate any advice or ideas. Thank you in advance

Comment: Fixed it, will post answer over two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to solve my problem:

```
LinearLayout animLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
animLayout.addView(//add some view);
animLayout.setId(1)
animLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
        switch (view.getId()}
        case 1:
            //My code
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Basically, give my view an ID and in my onTouch get the ID in a switch case and do what I want with it.

Answer (score 0):

check api reference first. see View.getY and Motionevent.getRawY.

Comment: Hi, downvote? I added a comment to my question. I solved the problem and will post what I did over two days. I wanted to use the onTouch view because it seemed more clean. I ended up setting an id for all the animated bits and just did what I wanted with them in the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` using a switch(view.getId()){case 1: //some code break;}.